# Async function with slow web reference(web service) slowing down webpage

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, web-services

Is there a way to make a threading/async post with a web reference not slow down the whole website just because the web reference takes a long time to return a response?

I have a send email function that gets posted async with a threading system that basically looks like this. This whole .cs file is called Mail.cs (that's where the Mail. name comes from).

```
public static bool SendMail(var alotOfVariablesHere)
{
    MailParameters param = new MailParameters(alotOfVariablesHere);
    Thread thread = new Thread(Mail.QueueSendMailAsyc);
    thread.Start(param);
    return true;

}

static Object locker = new object();
public static void QueueSendMailAsyc(object Objparam)
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        SendMailAsyc(Objparam);
    }
}
```

Inside `SendMailAsyc()` we run our web reference:

```
WebReference.Service1 Converter = new WebReference.Service1();
Converter.Timeout = 3 * 60 * 1000;

byte[] file = Converter.ConvertFunction(File.ReadAllBytes(attachfilepath), fileName);
```

The only thing the `WebReference` does is receiving a byte array and a file name and then returns a new byte array.

Pretty simple and it all works fine.

But recently the server were the web reference is sitting on (a totally different server from the webpage) has started getting really slow.
This means that the web reference takes a long time to respond (it does respond and it does return everything like the way we want it. just that it's now a lot slower)

And this has started causing a lot of issues, like:
The webpage also get really slowed down, it takes ages to navigate through the pages and so on.

Plus the fact that this one single web reference threading/async post takes so long time means that there is plenty of time to put up even more threading/async posts meaning it'll put an even bigger pressure on the server, causing it to slow down a lot.

This issue is primary that the web reference has gotten really slow lately, and that our webpage server cannot handle the pressure of too many threads/async posts.

I can't do much about the server the web reference is sitting on has started getting really slow recently.

But is there anything I can do code-wise to make my system handle this really slow web reference better?

Comment: "After this we run SendMailAsyc function. This function itself is kinda too big to be posted here." Red flag for me. This screams "my function is very big and ugly and I know it must be split up but I can't let you because it's not relevant". What about still posting that bit of code?

Comment: @Pimgd It's just a lot of strings here and there plus variable checks. And it all gets completed within 0.1 seconds. The issue here is the web reference and how to deal with it

Comment: 0.1 seconds is a very, very long time for a computer.

Comment: @rolfl notice the "within" part. At worst it might go up to 0.1 seconds to run. The web reference however can take up to half a minute just to respond.

Comment: @HenrikP honestly I didn't read much of the question. Is the code running on the server or the client? Please explain why you made this choice.

Comment: @caseyr547 All code posted here is for my website, I can run this website both locally(visual studio) and live(on a web hosting server). 
But inside the code I call on a web reference/service, and this web service is on a different server, not the same server as my website.
And the reason why I have a web reference/service is because the web service is running various things I don't have available on my website server such as office word functions. But all code is fine and does what it should on both ends. Main issue here is that the web service server has gotten really slow lately

Comment: How does the performance of visual studio compare to (cringe) your server side code

Comment: @caseyr547 I would say they are about the same, and both run well. It's just the web service that takes a long time to respond which causes issues for my website since I can stack up a lot of async/threadings in that time

Comment: Is your lock statement blocking and causing the delay?

Comment: Or is the large amounts of threads running on your server causing the delay?

Comment: @caseyr547 It's the server where the web service is hosted on that is the main issue, but my website suffers from the slow responses since my website can stack up a lot of threads in that time. I am not sure whether it is because my website server cannot handle too many threads and get overloaded, or if there is something about the locks/threads and that'w why I'm asking here

Comment: Ok change then web service call to a wait or pause for an appropriate amount of time spawn the typical workload and see how performance is

Comment: That will test your servers thread handling

Comment: During that test you need to watch memory usage cause you may be suddenly exceeding the oses set for you and your program may be fragmenting in memory if that's the case you can use processes instead of thread

Answer (score 1):

There's not enough information here to tell you what's wrong, but I'll tell you what I would do differently regardless.

Manually spawning threads is something you should avoid doing, *especially* if there's a chance that thread is just going to wait on a lock.  As the remote service gets slower and your app gets busier, you'll have more and more idle threads taking up resources.  You can make a single mail thread that has new `param`s passed to it (in a thread-safe way).